# Is this a bug in django template re: forloop.parentloop.first or do I misunderstand?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
from django.template import Template, Context
template = Template("""
      {% for language in languages %}
        THIS IS forloop.parentloop.first +++++++++
        {% for tag in revision_tags %}
          {% for case in CASES %}
          <tr>
            {% if forloop.parentloop.first %}<th rowspan="6">{{ language|capfirst }}</th>{% endif %}
            {% if forloop.first %}<th rowspan="2">{{ tag }}</th>{% endif %}
            <th>{{ case|capfirst }}</th>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
""")

c = Context({
    'languages': ["english", "french"],
    'revision_tags': ["d", "s", "p"],
    'CASES': ["foo", "bar"],
})

h = template.render(c)
print h
```

I expect to see each language only once but I get them twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, I misunderstood. The test should be `{% if forloop.parentloop.first and forloop.first %}` to get 1 true per grand parent iteration, `language` in this case.

```
  {% for language in languages %}
    {% for tag in revision_tags %}
      {% for case in CASES %}
      <tr>
        {% if forloop.parentloop.first and forloop.first %}
        <th rowspan="6">{{ language|capfirst }}</th>
        {% endif %}
        {% if forloop.first %}<th rowspan="2">{{ tag }}</th>{% endif %}
        <th>{{ case|capfirst }}</th>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this(not tested)...

```
{% for language in languages %}
    THIS IS forloop.parentloop.first +++++++++
    {% for tag in revision_tags %}
      {% if forloop.parentloop.first %}<th rowspan="6">{{ language|capfirst }}</th>{% endif %}
      {% for case in CASES %}
      <tr>
        {% if forloop.first %}<th rowspan="2">{{ tag }}</th>{% endif %}
        <th>{{ case|capfirst }}</th>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```